# Calculate the distance between two coordinates with Python

Tags: python, distance, haversine

I have a map where they find several points (lat/long) and want to know the distance that exists between them.

So, given a set of lat/long coordinates, how can I compute the distance between them in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I once wrote a python version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27943/4909087) answer. It details the use of the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate the distance in kilometers.

```
import math

def get_distance(lat_1, lng_1, lat_2, lng_2): 
    d_lat = lat_2 - lat_1
    d_lng = lng_2 - lng_1 

    temp = (  
         math.sin(d_lat / 2) ** 2 
       + math.cos(lat_1) 
       * math.cos(lat_2) 
       * math.sin(d_lng / 2) ** 2
    )

    return 6373.0 * (2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(temp), math.sqrt(1 - temp)))
```

Ensure the coordinates being passed to the function are in radians. If they're in degrees, you can convert them first:

```
lng_1, lat_1, lng_2, lat_2 = map(math.radians, [lng_1, lat_1, lng_2, lat_2])
```

Comment: The output is in meters?, that not worked for me.

Comment: The output is in Km, for meters was neded add *1000 to return

Comment: you must convert to radian first: lon_1, lat_1, lon_2, lat_2 = map(math.radians, [lon_1, lat_1, lon_2, lat_2])

Comment: @pepece I'd implicitly assumed the coords to be in radians since that's how I wrote the function for myself. Added a note in the answer, thanks for pointing it out!